# SharePoint task assignment email notification is not sent to user ... when having no access to the list?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-email, notifications

Is this a standard within SharePoint that the e-mail notification **will not** be sent to the assigned user if they do not have at least read access to the actual Task List?

Is this an intentional behaviour?

Looking from a different view, then it makes sense because the user should be part of the task in order to be notified BUT then there is no other way for the user to know / identify that he has a task assigned and is completely unaware?

I would have thought that the user would get the email, even if they have no access to the list as yet, but at least would be notified and of course when they try to navigate to the link provided in the email > it would say something like "sorry, no access" .

Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

You mean email notification about created task. User must have Contribute/Approve permission to the Task List, cause he need to approve (change) the task.

There is no another way, cause he need have proper permissions on list item in Task List for approving it.

If you want only notify user, use method send email not create a task.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: I am confused now :( well, within the Task List > Advance > you can set Send e-mail when ownership is assigned? to Yes which means to notify a user when I have assigned a Task to a user .... but the user does not get notified via email at all because he has no access to the Task List. However, having read/edit access then yes it works :)  - my question was why this is and if this is by default?

Comment: also, the user does not need to APPROVE a task ... it is all about notifying the user and yes if they want to add information or change or even set it to "completed" then, this is ok .... but the question is :) if the user does not have access to the Task List > why do they not get the email notification never the less?

Comment: its because the EventReciever - Notify in List or Library is based on when Item is Created/Added and its Permission based, so if user has not permissions to the list/library, the event reciever will never catch a new item here

Comment: its by design..

Comment: hmmm I suspected it be by design and the only way is to create a workflow. Shame, because ideally the user should be notified whether he user got read access or not.

Comment: you can create Notify WF in Task List where you will sending emails about created Task, but I dont understand why you want it, if the user cannot open/approve the task

Comment: @Zdenek ... it is not me wanting it :) I am just inquiring if this behaviour is standard in the SharePoint environment.  This case was brought up from the management meeting where they complaint "a manager was not notified about a task assigned to him..." - as it turned out to be a case of the manager not having access to the list to begin with. Hence my question :)

Comment: its standard behaviour, but when you create task, user is automatically notified with email (if you have set properly sending emails in SP)